# Как повернуть стрелочку вниз когда раскрывающийся список раскрыт?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет всем!
Есть раскрывающийся список, со стрелочкой справа, которая должна изменяться в зависимости от раскрыт список или свернут.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда его раскрываю, то стрелочка ведет себе как надо, смотрит вниз.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при повторном сворачивании списка, стрелка так и смотрит вниз, не изменяется. А должна смотреть вверх. Делаю это вот так:

```
$('.list_title').click( function() {
  $('.list_content').slideToggle() 
  $('.listBgArr').addClass('uppArrow');
});
```

То есть когда кликаю на `list_title`, раскрывается список и к стрелке добавляется класс `uppArrow`, который в css меняет `background-position` у css-спрайта стрелки. Может кто-то поможет почему так происходит?

Comment: `toggleClass` вместо `addClass`

Comment: @Oleksandr, блин. А я мучился почти сутки. Спасибо буду знать. Ставлю палец вверх.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Комментарий от @Oleksandr решил вопрос - `toggleClass вместо addClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Небольшая альтернатива:

CSS:

```
.usefull-links:hover{cursor: pointer;}
.usefull-links{position: relative;background-color: #5dcef9;padding: 5px 10px;border-radius: 5px;}
i.flaticon-down-arrow{position: absolute;right: 15px;bottom: 0px;}
.links{display: none;position: absolute;}
.links a{display: block;}
.info-div{position: relative;padding-top: 20px;}
.info-div i{transition: ease all 0.5s;}
.info-div .active i{transform: rotate(180deg);}
```

HTML:

```
        <div class="col-lg-4 info-div">
            <div class="usefull-links">Usefull links<i class="flaticon-down-arrow"></i></div>
            <div class="links">
                <a href="https://jquery.com/download/" target="_blank">Get jQuery</a>
                <a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/" target="_blank">Get bootstrap</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
$('.usefull-links').bind('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('.links').slideToggle();
});
```